# White Space in XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to work with an xml file from SBA api.

> http://api.sba.gov/loans_grants/federal_and_state_financing_for/ny.xml

The problem is when I try to parse this xml with xpath I get this error:

> [Fatal Error] loans_grants.dtd:3:22: White space is required before
>   the attribute type in the declaration of attribute "CDATA" for element
>   "count". Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   White space is required before the attribute type in the declaration
>   of attribute "CDATA" for element "count".

After observing the xml file I think the problem is in following lines and similar lines after that:

`<grant_loans count="103">`

`<industry nil="true"/>`

`<state_name nil="true"/>`

I think if there were space between `count` and `"103"` and `nil` and `"true"` then this error would not happen. As the whole xml is too big I copied some portion of it and made these changes and saved in my local storage. Then I could run and parse it without error. I just put some spaces like this:

```
<grant_loans count = "103">
```

How can I do this with my program to all places that requires space and then use that for further parsing?

I can post my java code here if you need but that code is working for other xml files, so I think this xml file has the problem.

**Edit**

Java code segment:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc = null;
    XPathExpression expr = null;
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = (Document) builder
            .parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway&sensor=false");

    // Create a XPathFactory
    XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a XPath object
    XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

    // Compile the XPath expression
    expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat/text()");
    System.out.println("expr" + expr);
    // Run the query and get a nodeset
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    // Cast the result to a DOM NodeList
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());  
    }

                       //this works
// 
// some other code
//
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    url = "http://api.sba.gov/loans_grants/federal_and_state_financing_for/ny.xml";
    doc = builder.parse(url); // problem occurs here
    xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a XPath object
    xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

    // Compile the XPath expression
    expr = xpath.compile("//grant_loan/url/text()");
    result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    // Cast the result to a DOM NodeList
    nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }

//other stuffs
```

Comment: xml does not require spaces like that.  your problem lies elsewhere (or you are using a broken xml parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the XML. It's telling you that [the DTD](http://api.sba.gov/dtd/loans_grants.dtd) is jacked up. Note the `loans_grants.dtd:3:22` at the beginning of the error. It's pointing at line 3:

```
<!ATTLIST count CDATA>
```

which should probably instead read

```
<!ATTLIST grant_loans count CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

The error is pointing out that the [proper format](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_attributes.asp) of an `ATTLIST` is:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type default-value>
```

It saw the string "CDATA" in the third position, assumed that was the attribute-name, and still expected to get an attribute-type, but instead, it found the end of the `ATTLIST`. That's why it gave the potentially confusing message about expecting white space.

Most likely, when you copied some of the xml to run against locally, you left off the DTD declaration, which would also solve the problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing it. But still, how can I have it so that I can work with it. I have no control over the xml or DTD provided by SBA. I have to somehow use it.

Comment: Well, I can think of a couple of things to try. First, you might be able to trick your XML parser into looking somewhere else for the DTD. Then you can make it load a correct one, or maybe just an empty one and turn off validation. Otherwise, perhaps you could strip the doctype declaration out of the XML before you pass it to the parser.

Comment: can you give me some starting point on any of the suggestions you gave? I am trying to strip the DTD right now. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Without knowing what parser you're using, I couldn't guess how to make it ignore the DTD or use a different one. As for stripping the DTD out of the file, it's not doing you any good since it's invalid, so I don't see how removing it can hurt.

Comment: If you're loading the whole document into memory at once, a simple regex find/replace should easily remove the DTD. Something like `xmlString.replaceFirst("<!DOCTYPE.*?>", "")`.

Comment: I have included my java code segment for you. Thanks for the helpful suggestions.